# Starting NUnit runner (2.6.3) from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nunit

I followed the instructions [here](http://erraticdev.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/running-or-debugging-nunit-tests-from.html) to use "start external program" to start NUnit on my test project's dll. NUnit starts, but I get an error  "This assembly was not built with any known testing framework"

I can run the same assembly with the same NUnit.exe from the command line just fine...

nunit.exe version 2.6.3

nunit.exe.config is as follows:

```
<configuration>
  <!--
   The GUI only runs under .NET 2.0 or higher. The
   useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy setting only
   applies under .NET 4.0 and permits use of mixed 
   mode assemblies, which would otherwise not load 
   correctly.
  -->
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <!-- Comment out the next line to force use of .NET 4.0 -->
    </startup>
    <runtime>
        <!-- Ensure that test exceptions don't crash NUnit -->
        <legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy enabled="1"/>
        <!-- Run partial trust V2 assemblies in full trust under .NET 4.0 -->
        <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
        <!-- Look for addins in the addins directory for now -->
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <probing privatePath="lib;addins"/>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, the answer is that I had to put the Command line argument in quotes.

e.g.

```
"C:\SVN\_branches\BUG-2261\Product\ProductTests\bin\Debug\ProductTests.dll"
```

I thought at first that this might be because there were spaces in the folder path for the dll but there aren't. It still need the quotes to make it work.